# What is the default username and password for Grafana login page?

Tags: analytics, grafana

what is default username and password for Grafana for http://localhost:3000/login page ? attaching a home page screenshot also.[image]
I want to watch mySql database for through it.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

[By looking up the docs](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/#security) we can find that the magic combo is `admin` as username and `admin` as password.

However if you changed some configuration file you should be able to find it there.
The default config file can be found here: `$WORKING_DIR/conf/defaults.ini` and can be overridden using the `--config` parameter

The item in the config you're looking for should be in the section:

```
[security]
admin_user = admin
admin_password = admin
```

Comment: Is this true, that in 2019, they store password in clear text in a file?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar that's the default password, if i'm correct it'll store the password hashed and salted in the database: https://community.grafana.com/t/local-authentication-password-encrypted-or-not/1594 and one may specify a given password

Comment: from documentation: " if grafana_admin_passwd is not set, the password defaults to prom_operator." https://docs.openstack.org/releasenotes/magnum/stein.html

Comment: @david your comment is about a whole another project which uses grafana. They set up their default password to be what you specified which was already given by @Tinkaal in the answer below. The default password for just grafana still remains `admin` to this day.

Answer (score 83):

If you are using **Prometheus Operator** then user/pass is:

```
user: admin
pass: prom-operator
```

Install prometheus-operator using helm:

```sh
#helm3
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com

helm install my-prometheus-operator stable/prometheus-operator
```

Comment: I don't get why this answer got >50 upvotes when it relates to a completely different software product. Has the question been edited so we do not see the connection anymore?

Comment: @MOnsDaR no it has not been edited except for tags. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54039604/revisions

Comment: Which is even more confusing...

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem.  I changed the password after the first login and then forgot what it was.  However, I was able to fix it by using the grafana-CLI through the docker container.  At the command line:

```
docker exec -it <name of grafana container> grafana-cli admin reset-admin-password <fill in password>
```

This resets the admin password back to "admin".  When you log in to grafana again, you will be prompted to change the password to something better.

Comment: I had to use `docker exec -ti grafana_container_name grafana-cli admin reset-admin-password new_password`

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer worked in the past, but for me it didn't work and I had to use the way Fredrik Wendt mentioned. It's also documented: https://grafana.com/docs/administration/cli/

Comment: Also, after reset pod reboot was required in my case

Answer (score 25):

Default credentials for Grafana

```
username: admin
password: admin
```

Answer (score 16):

In K8s, to get user/pass of grafana pod, do the following

Get pods and find out what's the name of grafana pod

```
kubectl get pod
```

Describe `grafana` pod:

```
kubectl describe pod my-release-grafana-7f59ddb678-r4jq4
```

Or simple in one command (if you deployed it in helm chart)

```
kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=grafana,app.kubernetes.io/instance=my-release"
```

The output should look like the following:

```
...
Environment:                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER:      <set to the key 'admin-user' in secret 'my-release-grafana'>      Optional: false                                                                                                                     
   GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'admin-password' in secret 'my-release-grafana'>  Optional: false
    ...
```

get user name and password from secret:

```
kubectl get secret my-release-grafana -oyaml
```

this should give you something similar to the following output:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  admin-password: T1lsV0ZPY2liM05Ceml5cVZkVmk3N1ZqWWtrS0phU3Jjdm9sMTNkWA==
  admin-user: YWRtaW4=
  ldap-toml: ""
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: my-release
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  creationTimestamp: "2021-08-11T20:12:34Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: my-release
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: grafana
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 8.1.0
    helm.sh/chart: grafana-6.15.0
  name: my-release-grafana
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "842508"
  uid: 3d3326fb-a7c8-4382-9abc-8ffd2f4d7a11
type: Opaque
```

decode user name and password

```
echo "T1lsV0ZPY2liM05Ceml5cVZkVmk3N1ZqWWtrS0phU3Jjdm9sMTNkWA==" | base64 --decode
```

Answer (score 5):

default grafana login is

```
username: admin
password: admin
```

here is a linux tutorial on how to reset grafana admin password if you lost it https://codesposts.com/Wg04jK59

Answer (score 5):

**grafana 7.3.5**

admin:prom-operator

admin:password

root:admin

root:password

administrator:admin

**grafana 9.4**

admin:admin

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing is reset the password, if you don't have docker installed in your cluster you can use kubectl

```
kubectl exec -it <name of your pods> -n <name of your namespace> grafana-cli admin reset-admin-password <your reset password>
```

so it will look like this

```
kubectl exec -it grafna-haks1k2-628181 -n my-grafana grafana-cli admin reset-admin-password admin
```

remember: when you don't have a specific namespace in your cluster for Grafana you can remove -n my-grafana.

good luck

Comment: I deployed using the Bitnami Helm chart and mounted a custom grafana.ini, and for some reason the default password it generates wasn't working. Your command did the trick! Got to learn about grafana-cli as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
kubectl get secret --namespace $NAMESPACE grafana \
    -o jsonpath="{.data.admin-password}" | base64 --decode ; echo
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your Docker Compose for this:

```
environment:
  - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD={{YOUR-PASS-WILL-BE-HERE}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Default password for grafana is "admin" for admin user. you can change the same on setting.

Answer (score 1):

With `grafana-5.1.4`chart the user name is `admin` and the password is `password` :)

Answer (score 0):

Run the command below to get the admin user and password.

```
k get secret kube-prometheus-stack-grafana -o yaml
```

The name and password are encrypted as base64. Copy the password and name separately and decode using the command below

```
echo <encoded-admin-user> | base64 -d
```

Replace `<encoded-admin-user>` with the text from the secret yaml.
Do same for the admin-password